# Algorithm for generating carrier unlocking codes for phones

Tags: algorithm

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here I go:

> Is there a general algorithm which generates the MEP code given the [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) and PRD codes of the phone? Is the algorithm public? If yes, where can it be found?

I recently bought a carrier locked phone and I found a site where they gave me the unlock code instantly (for 3$). Therefore, I guess they have an algorithm which gives the unlock code instantly.

Comment: So you're asking how to circumvent the terms of your contract with your carrier..?

Comment: Yeah it isn't the place to ask such questions. But for the sake of answering, go check out some YoutTube videos. I can see people telling how to do such stuff. I haven't gone through those videos though, so don't come yelling at me if you don't get your desired solution. :D

Comment: @Michael: I have no contract with any carrier. I bought a locked phone so I unlocked it. I ask if there is a general algorithm to calculate the code, or every phone has a different formula.

Comment: Hm, might be a better question at [security.SE] or [SU], but I'm not sure

Comment: You've read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlock_phone?